# Suddenly notification is not working (Mirror API)

Tags: php, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I have installed glass APK in my mobile. I have created a APP in MIRROR API with PHP(web services). This was working since for 4-5 months, but suddenly this is stop working. When I tap in mobile and share anything with contacts, the web service is not getting called (in error log file nothing is writable).

My subscribed notification url is  - 
https://mirrornotifications.appspot.com/forward?url=http://mydomainname/appname/notify.php
And I can see the subscription list when I print the subscription.

I have checked, everything is fine and I am also getting timeline when running PHP script manually.

I am totally surprised as it is suddenly stop working for only notification.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Glass app on an Android phone, not on Glass itself? This sounds like a **very** unsupported configuration, so I'm not surprised that it might have broken. In the past few weeks, the Glass software has been updated and been rebased to a new version of Android, so I wouldn't rule out that the wire protocol also changed.